# CSS animation from left to right appearing to get closer & further away, simulating the motion of a glass on a turntable platter front viewed

Tags: css, css-animations

I am trying to create a CSS animation that moves horizontally from left to right while appearing to get closer and further away, simulating the motion of a glass on a turntable platter viewed from the front.

I have got close but its still not looking right, looks like at the moment its travelling along a diamond shape rather than a circle.

Here is what I have tried..

```css
.roll {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
  animation: roll 2s cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1) infinite;
}

@keyframes roll {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0%) scale(1);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translateX(50%) scale(0.8);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(0%) scale(0.6);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateX(-50%) scale(0.8);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="roll"></div>
```

Comment: Is the glass actually to look like a 3D object or, as in your example, is the same ‘face’ always to present to the viewer?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to **animate the square on a horizontal plane circle and keep it facing the viewer**, you can use 3d transforms on a wrapper element and resverse it on the square so it stays facing the viewer.

The point is to rotate the element on the Y axis as it would "in real life".
Here is an example :

```css
.wrap {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;  
  margin: 50px auto 50px auto;
  animation: roll 2s linear infinite;
  transform-origin: 50% 50% -250px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.roll {
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  background: red;
  animation: roll 2s linear infinite reverse;
  transform-origin: 50% 50% 0;
}

@keyframes roll {
  from { transform:  perspective(1200px) rotateY(0deg);}
  to { transform:  perspective(1200px) rotateY(-360deg);}
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="roll"></div>
</div>
```

Note that you need to use `transform-style: preserve-3d;` ([more info on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-style))

Comment: Thats almost spot on to what im trying to do but without the pause in the middle so it jsut smoothly continues around. +1 for spotting I wanted the face to stay forwards as i forgot to mention that in the OP.

Comment: @GlenKeybit Glad I could help ! For that you need to change the animation easing function to `linear`. I updated my answer with that value ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this 3d effect by playing with the z-axis. Have a look: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translateZ

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  background: tomato;
  perspective: 500px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  animation: roll 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes roll {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg) translatez(110px) scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg) translatez(110px) scale(0.5)
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(360deg) translatez(110px) scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```